# apt-get update : Unable to change to (unreachable)// - chdir (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: apt, updates, package-management

Today I have tried to update the package lists and I have encountered strange error

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-proposed/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-proposed/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-proposed/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 496 kB in 38s (13.0 kB/s)
E: Unable to change to (unreachable)// - chdir (2: No such file or directory)
```

What should I change now ? Something in `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: Please see this, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/771780

Comment: Can you help me on what should I do in this situation ?

Comment: Is that Saucy installed or Beta version?

Comment: Does not look like I can of much assistance. The only advice we find there is something in the line of not detaching your drive while updating a system. Did you do something like that? If the answer is yes, do you want to try reattaching the drive and running update again? Good luck.

Comment: @Braiam That's Saucy installed.

Comment: When I asked if it's Saucy, I meant, clean installation of Saucy?

Comment: @Braiam It is an upgrade from 13.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling `libapt-pkg` helped .

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libapt-pkg4.12
```

Answer (score 11):

I got this error message every time I ran `sudo apt-get update` with an encrypted home directory, while I was in my home directory.

If I cd'd to `/` first, the error went away.

(Ubuntu Server 13.10)

Comment: I found my self in a removable disk that I had ejected. Changing into my home folder got me going again. This put me on the right path (literally).

Comment: This worked for me on 14.04 Server

Comment: Worked for me, but I would like to understand why. Do you have pointers that may explain this?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi probably the directory isn't accessible by root (for encryption reasons) or some other user that the apt-get process `setuid`s to.

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen today. It was because my current directory was mounted with sshfs. I don't know if it would occur with any FUSE file system or just sshfs, but the answer was to just get out of that directory. That is:

```
cd
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when my current dir was a cluster fs. https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_Cluster_File_System_(pmxcfs)
change your current directory to a folder with a different file system.
e.g. cd /