# Can I have a different $HOME for myself as sudo?

Tags: sudo, home-directory

In our network, all user and group IDs are distributed through NIS from a central server and each user's `$HOME` directory is on a mounted folder which lives on that central server.

Obviously the user has a different GID from `root` and so `root` doesn't have access to the mounted `$HOME` folder, making it difficult (if not impossible) for the user to run something like `sudo apt update` as this needs access to `$HOME` as seen by `sudo`.

My question is, can I have a machine-local `$HOME` for the files & folders that `sudo` needs access to while the `$HOME` for my other (non-`sudo`) work keeps pointing to the mounted folder?

Additional information:

```
[user@machine ~]$ id
uid=544(user) gid=40(src) groups=40(src),101(systemd-journal)

[user@machine ~]$ sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),40(src),101(systemd-journal),600(visitors),13010(hlcc),19016(identhw),51107(cadadm)

[user@machine ~]$ sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/net/server/home/user

[user@machine ~]$ sudo sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/net/server/home/user
```

How can I change the result of the last line (i.e. the `sudo` version of `$HOME`) point to a local folder on `machine` instead of the mounted network path?

### Edit:

Thanks for the answers. Turns out my question was almost identical to [this one on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91384/55900).

I also found out that the problem I had with `apt-get update` wasn't actually related to the `HOME` environment variable, instead it was related to the fact that I was calling `sudo apt-get update` from my (`user`'s) home folder, similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/372290/181442) which can be solved by simply calling `sudo apt-get update` from another folder, e.g. `/`.

But since my question here was more about the `HOME` seen by `sudo`, I accepted [techraf's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/861169/181442) because it doesn't require any additional switches or definitions in the `sudo` command line.

Comment: Why not just invoke `sudo -i` and have it use root's home on the local machine?

Comment: Learnt a lot from your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following line to sudoers Command Environment section (with `sudo visudo`).

```
Defaults        env_keep -= "HOME"
```

Then you can use your scripts without changes.

---

There is a difference between Debian and Ubuntu in a way `sudo` command handles by default the `HOME` variable (specifically this variable, not the whole environment):

- In Debian `HOME` value is replaced with the root's (target user's) home directory;
- Ubuntu preserves the calling user's setting.

[This answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91572/133107) contains more details.

Answer (score 7):

If you invoke sudo with `-i` you will get root's home.

If you want sudo to inherit from the current environment you could just set home to something else.

So, either use `sudo -i command` or do `HOME=/wherever sudo command`.

For example:

```
sudo -i sh -c 'echo $HOME'
```

Which gives you:

```
/root
```

Or:

```
HOME=/foo sudo sh -c 'echo $HOME'
```

Which gives you:

```
/foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a way to change the HOME variable for `sudo`ing without having to type something extra on the command line? Your solution breaks scripts that just call `sudo` without the `-i` or the explicit HOME assignment.

Comment: Not really.  The choice is to either inherit from the environment or the environment of the target user.  You could always make a shell script that you call instead of having to type it each time, though.  If you don't want to break scripts you could possibly use an alias that calls a script and sets up the environment.