# apt install warns that .dpkg.cfg for reading: Permission denied

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg, nfs

My setup is the following: my user is logged in via a network authentication, its home is NFS mounted (all of this on ubuntu 16.04).

I am trying to set up my machine so running multiple `apt` commands like `update` or `install`:

- `update` fails with `E: Unable to change to /home/$user/ - chdir (13: Permission denied)`. I managed to quick-fix it with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372290/apt-get-update-unable-to-change-to-unreachable-chdir-2-no-such-file-or), basically `cd /`
- `install` warns me that: `dpkg: warning: failed to open configuration file '/home/zr258722/.dpkg.cfg' for reading: Permission denied`.

How should I get rid of those errors/warnings?

---

EDIT

The exact commands I am running and their outputs are:

- `sudo apt-get update` which gives:

```
Ign:1 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/drf-i2bm_pilote xenial-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/drf-i2bm_pilote xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/drf-i2bm_pilote xenial InRelease
Ign:4 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/saclay_pilote xenial-security InRelease
Ign:5 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/saclay_pilote xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/saclay_pilote xenial InRelease
Ign:7 http://$intranet/depots/neurodebian/current data InRelease            
Ign:8 http://$intranet/depots/neurodebian/current xenial InRelease                                                             
Ign:9 http://$intranet/depots/ubuntu/current xenial-security InRelease                                                         
Ign:10 http://$intranet/depots/ubuntu/current xenial-updates InRelease                                                         
Ign:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                           
Ign:12 http://$intranet/depots/ubuntu/current xenial InRelease                                                                 
Hit:13 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/drf-i2bm_pilote xenial-security Release                
Hit:14 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/drf-i2bm_pilote xenial-updates Release                                       
Hit:15 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/drf-i2bm_pilote xenial Release                                               
Hit:16 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/saclay_pilote xenial-security Release                                        
Hit:17 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/saclay_pilote xenial-updates Release                                         
Hit:18 http://$intranet/depots/infogerance/ubuntu/saclay_pilote xenial Release                                                 
Hit:19 http://$intranet/depots/neurodebian/current data Release                                                                
Hit:20 http://$intranet/depots/neurodebian/current xenial Release                                                              
Hit:21 http://$intranet/depots/ubuntu/current xenial-security Release                                                          
Hit:22 http://$intranet/depots/ubuntu/current xenial-updates Release                                                           
Hit:23 http://$intranet/depots/ubuntu/current xenial Release                                                                
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                   
Hit:25 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                    
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:28 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                   
Reading package lists... Done                     
E: Unable to change to /home/$user/ - chdir (13: Permission denied)
```

- for example `sudo apt-get python3.6` which gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev libpython3.6 libpython3.6-dev python3.5-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  python3.6-venv python3.6-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3.6
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/246 kB of archives.
After this operation, 336 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: failed to open configuration file '/home/$user/.dpkg.cfg' for reading: Permission denied
Selecting previously unselected package python3.6.
(Reading database ... 375863 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3.6_3.6.8-1~16.04.york1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.6 (3.6.8-1~16.04.york1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
dpkg: warning: failed to open configuration file '/home/$user/.dpkg.cfg' for reading: Permission denied
Setting up python3.6 (3.6.8-1~16.04.york1) ...
dpkg: warning: failed to open configuration file '/home/$user/.dpkg.cfg' for reading: Permission denied
dpkg: warning: failed to open configuration file '/home/$user/.dpkg.cfg' for reading: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Your home folder should have at least the following permissions: `u=rwx,g=r,o=r`, run `chmod 0711 /home/$user`

Comment: Thanks, this solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Normally root doesn't have permissions to access NFS mounts, unless no_root_squash is set for the export, apt-get runs in root context with sudo and can't access the home directory.
This is an annoying but harmless warning, which can be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the installation happens such that it looks as if not the user but the program is asking for the permission.You could try to change the permissions of the offending folder to

> chmod 777 offending_foldername

this would give all users to read,write and execute. If this solves the problem you could probably look deeper and fix the issue for network security reasons.

Comment: which part of my question are you referring to? `update` or `install` or both?

Comment: 777 is almost *never* a good idea. Especially do not change permissions of system files or directories recursively unless you exactly know what you do, as that may break the system beyond repair.

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't know it could break the system entirely.